# Why doesn't sin() return the correct value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

How do I use `sin()`, `cos()`, and `tan()` functions in iOS application? When I use this I didn't get the correct value. Example:

```
double value=sin(90);
```

I got value: 0.893997 but expected value: 1. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that it's taking the sine of 90 *radians*, not *degrees*. Try `sin(M_PI_2)` for 90°.

Comment: How can i apply Please help me

Comment: @VineeshTP The functions use radians, not degrees. He told you how to get 90° -- to convert degrees to radians use `degrees * π / 180`, so you can do something like sin( 90 * M_PI / 180 ) which reduces to `π / 2` or `M_PI_2`.