# sinf() and cosf() in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, ios-simulator, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't sin() return the correct value here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663965/why-doesnt-sin-return-the-correct-value-here)

I am building an app which will perform math operations like sine (`sinf()`) and cosine (`cost()`) on `floats`. Now when I tried calculating the sinus on 90 (which is 1), I got a result of 0.89... which is trebly wrong. Is there a reason why the result is so off? is there a way to improve it? I have tried using `double` instead of `float` and got the same answer... Is it possible it's only like than when I run it in the simulator, and will work fine on a real iPhone?
And lastly, will using a math parser like `GCMathParser` or  `DDMathParser` improve there accuracy of the results?

Thanks, :]

Comment: Every language that I know of uses radians in its trig functions.  Every single one: FORTRAN, C, C++, Java, JavaScript, C#....

Comment: I am used to using MATLAB for mathematical programming, and in MATLAB degrees are used by the sin() and cos() methods...

Comment: well according to my teacher at least....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, it's taking the sine of 90 radians, not degrees. Try sin(M_PI_2) for 90°

The functions use radians, not degrees.

To convert degrees to radians use degrees * π / 180, so you can do something like sin( 90 * M_PI / 180 ) which reduces to π / 2 or M_PI_2

[Why doesn't sin() return the correct value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663965/why-doesnt-sin-return-the-correct-value-here)

Answer (score 10):

The `sinf` and `cosf` functions use radians. You have to convert first:

```
float result = sinf(yourDegree / 180 * M_PI);
```

Answer (score 2):

As always: [these functions work in radians](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin), not degrees.

Try calculating the sine of `π/2`, which is 90° in radians.

Answer (score 1):

The trig functions in objective-c take angles in radians. You are giving the argument in degrees. the sin of 90 radians is 0.89.

see:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2890+rad%29

To convert to degrees, simply divide the # of degrees by 180, and multiply by pi (3.14159 is good enough as an approximation)

once converted, the answer is 1 as expected.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2890*pi%2F180+rad%29